# Aligning TextView and AutoCompleteTextView side by side in Android

Tags: java, android, layout, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to align the following AutoCompleteTextView (Type group location..) and the TextView (Radius) to the left, regarding the top ImageView.

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't work.
Here's my xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp">


<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/radiusText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autocomplete_textview"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I already tried and failed:

Aligning the TextView with the regard to the AutoCompleteTextView, and also aligning both views with regard to parent view.

I suspect the AutoCompleteTextView has some transparent trailing, or I'm missing something.

Comment: Try with layout_gravity and gravity.

Comment: I did not get you, do you want all of them in single line?

Comment: Which SDK are you supporting? Try sdk 23 and sdk 19 (for example). Did you notice any difference?

Comment: I ask you this, because I copy your layout in a project and i notice that, in layout editor (visual mode) when i change sdk to 23 to 19 the component text become aligned. I'm working with Android Studio 1.4. And you?

Comment: I want all to be aligned on the left.
As you see, the AutoCompleteTextView has some small padding to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my solution at least.

For some reason AutoCompleteTextView has default padding, once I set the paddingLeft to 0, it fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to your AutoCompleteTextView  and TextView

```
  android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want it like this:
[image: Vertical]

then use vertical Linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView5" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_setting_light"/>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:hint="Location here"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:hint="Radius(in meters)"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or if you want like this:
[image: Horizontal]

Use horizontal LinearLayout with weights:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_setting_light"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.5">
     <AutoCompleteTextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="Location"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1.0">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Radius (m)"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Replace the image with your home and give the required ids.

Comment: I really don't find it a smart idea, to surround every View with a RelativeLayout, in your second proposal. This doesn't help flattening (which must be pursued for best performances).

Comment: ya, you can assign weights directly to widgets instead of putting them in a relative layout

Comment: You really should. So, you'd get rid of 3 useless layouts.

Comment: Same problem occurs on LinearLayout, still has some small annoying padding to the AutoCompleteTextView